# Assign textwriter to memory writer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am writing an `xml` file but am missing some value for specific field. I check that when the object comes which contains the value that specific value exist, but after writing the `xml` the value doesn't exist.

This is the code that I use, I think `XmlTextWriter` could be the cause of the wrong `xml`.

There is another method which could be used for it, that is `TextWriter` but it failed to convert into memorystream.

```
string xmlString = null;
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
// XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.ASCII);
TextWriter xmlTextWriter=new StreamWriter(memoryStream,Encoding.ASCII);
xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj);
memoryStream =(MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.    
//(MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
xmlString = ASCIIByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray()); 
return `xmlString;`
```

Any idea how I can know why and where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 13):

I think you are over-complicating it with the memory stream. You can serialize to a StringWriter (which derives from TextWriter) then call ToString() if you want to get the XML string.

```
string str;
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
{
   xs.Serialize(sw, obj);
   str = sw.ToString();
}
return str;
```

Comment: I didn't answer your question.  Just fixed a spelling mistake.

Comment: you will have to post more code for us to see where the problem lies. currently we can't even see where obj comes from so we have no way of telling where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try disposing properly your IDisposable resources by wrapping them in using statements:

```
public string SerializeToXml<T>(T obj)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        xs.Serialize(stream, obj);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```